# How to sort xml elements when their value mean different things like sorting prices but each price have different currency

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have an XML document which describes courses and their title price etc.,
and I want to generate an HTML document using XSLT where the output will be a table but the line should be sorted based on price from the lower to the most expensive but each course have different currency the rate will be hardcoded in XML through a new attribute called rate example " rate = 10.95 ". I have already sorted them but based on price only I didn't consider the currency.

This is my XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="q2.xsl"?>
<catalogue>
    <cours id="INFO-H-509" type="Informatique">
        <titre>Technologies XML</titre>
        <prix unite="Usd">4000</prix>
        <session num="1">
            <date>12-03-2015</date>
        </session>
        <session num="2">
            <date>28-12-2015</date>
        </session>
    </cours>
    <cours id="MATH-0-1" type="Mathematique">
        <titre>Recheche Opérationelle</titre>
        <prix unite="Euro">3000</prix>
        <session num="1">
            <date>12-03-2013</date>
        </session>
    </cours>
    <cours id="INFO-B-9" type="Informatique">
        <titre>Architecture client/serveur </titre>
        <professeur cin="AD456"/>
        <prix unite="Usd">5000</prix>
        <session num="1">
            <date>10-01-2016</date>
        </session>
    </cours>
</catalogue>
```

and this is my XSL file so far :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/catalogue">
        <html>
            <HEAD>
                <TITLE>Titre</TITLE>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="q1_style.css"/>

            </HEAD>
            <BODY>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Tableau qui resume le nombre d'ouvrage </h1>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr >
                            <th></th>
                            <th class="table-head">Type</th>
                            <th class="table-head">Nombre de session</th>
                            <th class="table-head">Prix</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="cours">
                            <xsl:call-template name="afficherCours">
                                <xsl:with-param name="cours" select="."></xsl:with-param>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </BODY>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="afficherCours">
        <xsl:param name="cours"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$cours/titre"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$cours/@type"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="count($cours/session)"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($cours/prix,' ',$cours/prix/@unite)">
                </xsl:value-of>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$cours/prix/@unite"></xsl:value-of> -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to sort in the shown XSLT code. If you want to convert prices in different currencies, where you want to get the rates from to convert e.g. EUR to USD?

Comment: the rate will be hardcoded no need te get it from a third-party application, I did the sorting using <xsl:sort select="prix"/> but I delete it since it just sorts based on the numbers

Comment: Will the rate be hardcoded in the XML? Or the XSLT?

Comment: *"the rate will be hardcoded in XML through a new attribute called rate"* Please edit your XML example to show **exactly** how this will look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `prix` element has a `rate` attribute, then you can probably sort using:

```
<xsl:sort select="prix * prix/@rate" data-type="number"/>
```

I say *probably*, because we don't have an actual example of the input XML.

Comment: it works thank you so much but can you explain to me what does data-type has to do with this instruction cause once I remove data-type it doesn't work

Comment: If you remove the `data-type` attribute, the sort will default to alphabetical order. This does work - just not the way you want.